# Why is pulling images using `--ignore-pull-failures` shows 404 failures the first time and done the second time

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this `docker-compose.yml` with some local images and some from a remote repository.

When running `docker-compose.yml pull --ignore-pull-failures` the first time, it shows this error for the local images (which is normal) :

> ERROR: 404 Client Error: Not Found ("pull access denied for my-local-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'")
>
> Pulling my-local-image   ... done

When running `docker-compose.yml pull --ignore-pull-failures` the second time, it only shows:

> Pulling my-local-image   ... done

When the 404 error should show up ? And why ?

Answer (score 0):

If your remote repository is from Docker Hub, log in before doing a pull, if the repo is private. With ...

```
docker login
```